# Sort edges in euclidean graph

Tags: graphs, computational-geometry

Given a euclidean graph $G$ and a node $p$ with edges to all the other nodes, is there a more efficient solution than $O(NLog(N))$ to output all the edges to $p$ in sorted order?

Comment: When you add a new node, what are its neighbors? If they're not specified "at birth", then there must be some geometric rule which determines which other nodes are connected to it. If you don't tell us this rule, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus tnx, I edit it.

Comment: What do you mean by Euclidean graph? Planar graph? How do you "create edges ... keeping it Euclidean"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory contains a definition of "euclidean graph" that I think is probably what is intended here.  It is a complete graph.  The vertices lie in the euclidean plane and the distance between vertices is given by their euclidean distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find a way to do this, then you can build a sorting algorithm that does it faster than the $\Omega(n \log n)$ boundary on comparison sort.

How you would build the sorting algorithm: let the values in an $n$-element array by $x_1,...,x_n$. Assume you can find the neighbors of a vertex on the euclidean plane sorted by distance in $\mathcal{o}(n \log n)$ time. Use the vertex $v_0 = (\text{min}_i \{x_i\} -1,0)$ as reference vertex, put vertices $v_1,...,v_n$ on the x-axis with $v_i = (x_i,0)$. Clearly, those points sorted by their euclidean distance from $v_0$ give you the order for the array as well. This way, you would get below the comparison-sort boundary of $\Omega(n \log n)$. Given that there is no known sorting algorithm like that that doesn't also have some other variables in its complexity, I'd expect that finding such an algorithm would be really hard.

Comment: But also note that any lower bound crucially depends on the model of computation. So does the $n \log n$ sorting bound. One can beat the $n \log n$ barrier for example in the RAM model, but apparently $O(n)$ isn't known (yet).

Comment: @Juho I'm not aware that the model is relevant to the proof that comparison sort is in $\Omega (n \log n)$ worst case. If I remember correctly, all it assumes is the number of permutations is $n!$ and that one comparison takes $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time, which should be true in the RAM model.

Comment: Yes, and *every* lower bound proof depends on the model of computation. I only wanted to stress that to make it explicit :-)

Comment: What about radix sort?

Comment: @RealzSlaw Yeah, radix sort and integer sorting are always possible, assuming our keys are some form of binary strings. But the complexities of those things have additional parameters in them that don't just depend on the number of input values, but also the distribution and size of input values.

Comment: @RealzSlaw I'll rephrase my answer, it isn't quite right the way it is.

Comment: The $\Omega(n\log n)$ is true in the algebraic decision tree model. This is a model in which your access to the input is given by your asking whether algebraic expressions are positive or negative. If that's all that babibu's algorithm does, you're done. As mentioned, in radix sort you use the values to index arrays, which is not covered by the algebraic decision tree model.